# Conditional module aliasing

Tags: module, ocaml

For a class project I am writing a program that evaluates the performance of different implementations of the same abstract data structure.  Since I am using identical code to test each of them, I would like to be able to set a module alias depending on user input and just run that module through the testing code.

In other words, I want something like:

```
let module M = 
  if model = "tree" then TreeModel else
  if model = "hash" then HashModel else
  ListModel
in ...
```

Is there a way I can make this work, or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no conditionals on the module level, but you can use first-class modules for this:

```
let m = match model with
  | "tree" -> (module TreeModel : MODEL)
  | "hash" -> (module HashModel : MODEL)
  | "list" -> (module ListModel : MODEL)
in let module M = (val m : MODEL)
in ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to @Andreas, at least in recent ocaml versions you can also write:

```
let (module M : MODEL) = match model with
  | "tree" -> (module TreeModel : MODEL)
  | "hash" -> (module HashModel : MODEL)
  | "list" -> (module ListModel : MODEL)
in ...
```

Comment: and with this form, you don't have to write the module type information in all match branches: `(module M : MODEL)` is enough and will propagate.

Comment: Not here. I would get `Error: The signature for this packaged module couldn't be inferred.` without the type annotation.

Comment: may be depend on the version of your compiler, but for me this is working: `let (module M : MODEL) = match model with | "tree" -> (module TreeModel) ...`